# How to determine USB Version 1.1 or 2.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I have got a Ubuntu server 9.10 system with a USB storage attached.

It works very, very slow. Is there a command to test whether it's 1.1 or 2.0 usb?

How can I find out?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Plug your device in, then see syslog:

> $ tail -n 2 /var/log/syslog
>   Dec 22 17:25:14 localhost kernel: [73348.931267] **usb 2-3**: new **high speed** USB device using ehci_hcd and address 13
>   Dec 22 17:25:14 localhost kernel: [73349.084555] usb 2-3: configuration #1 chosen from 3 choices

Note the device bus id there: `usb 2-3`.
Now get the version:

> $ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-3/version
>   2.00

Cheers! :)

Comment: So there is no way to do this without device attach?

Comment: @CAMOBAP How would you determine it without it being attached? It needs to be attached for the system to see it.

Comment: but why, AFAIK (maybe I'm wrong), both port and device have specified USB protocol version, and if you put USB 1.x device in USB 3.0 port it still will work by 1.x protocol. So why we cannot determine USB version of port by itself?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

lsusb -v

a simple way.

you should install usbutils first

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend this app (System Profiler and Benchmark)easy install and easy to understand device management window.
[Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTKGa.png)